# design a widget

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, jquery-ui

I want to design/use a widget like this.

[image]

My main intention is to vary the green/yellow/blue portion/percentage as per the need.
Is there any widget available like this.

Comment: Yes, there are PLENTY of graphing libraries around.

Comment: i am looking for options other than charts